# Link a thirdparty library that link by the depended library, use Cmake

Tags: cmake

In order to simplify the dependency, we use a wrapper library to wrap the thrid party libraries, like gradle. For example:

lib_wrapper -> thirdparty libs

A -> libWrapper

B -> libWrapper

So A, B can use the functions in thirdparty. But I the camke file I writed do not work.

lib_wrapper cmake file:

```
project(lib_wrapper)
# emty.c is an empty c file, do not use any ib_thirdparty funciton
add_library(lib_wrapper SHARED empty.c)

target_link_libraries(lib_wrapper lib_thirdparty1.a)
target_link_libraries(lib_wrapper lib_thirdparty2.a)
target_link_libraries(lib_wrapper lib_thirdparty3.a)
```

A's camke file:

```
project(alib)
add_library(A SHARED a.c)

# add dependency
add_subdirectory(${lib_wrapper_path} lib_wrapper/out)
add_dependencies(alib lib_wrapper)
add_library(lib_wrapper_import SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_wrapper_import PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/lib_wrapper_import.so")

target_link_libraries(alib lib_wrapper_import)
```

I also try PUBLIC or INTERFACE key word in `target_link_libraries`, but it does not work. Could some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to have the wrapper library as an interface library. For example:

```
project(lib_wrapper)
add_library(lib_wrapper INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(lib_wrapper lib_thirdparty1.a)
target_link_libraries(lib_wrapper lib_thirdparty2.a)
target_link_libraries(lib_wrapper lib_thirdparty3.a)
target_include_directories(lib_wrapper INTERFACE <enter the third party include folders here>)
```

and then in the project:

```
project(alib)
add_library(A SHARED a.c)

# add dependency
add_subdirectory(${lib_wrapper_path})
target_link_libraries(alib lib_wrapper)
```

this is actually the way how cmake can handle targets which are header only libraries. Calling `target_include_directories` for the interface library will also include all the include folders of the third party libraries, if you add the correct paths.

A more complete tutorial on interface targets in cmake can be found for example here: http://mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html